# Testing a Bipolar Junction Transistor using an analogue ohm-meter?

Tags: transistors, diodes, npn, ohmmeter

[This video](https://youtu.be/qM7_h8my8eA) says I should see ohmmeter deflection with an NPN transistor, placing positive probe on the base, and negative probe on collector or emitter.

A BC547 NPN is giving me opposite results - [ohmmeter](http://www.gardnerbender.com/en/gmt-319) deflection with negative probe on the base, and positive probe on collector or emitter.

I tested a simple rectifier diode with the same ohmmeter. I got meter deflection with positive probe on cathode, but no deflection with positive probe on anode. Does that help?

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to see what you are doing to tell you what you are doing wrong. Obviously something is wrong with your test setup, or you are mistaking the pin-out of the tranny.

Comment: Not all meters have a positive voltage on the positive probe when on the ohms range.  Traditional analogue meters were reversed.

Comment: Also be aware BC parts are pinned out differently from 2N parts. YOu are likely looking at the collector base junction.

Comment: @KevinWhite that's interesting, and surprising. I'm using a new GB meter, GMT-319.

Comment: @johnywhy: Test your meter on a diode to confirm Kevin's point.

Comment: Diode test result added to the OP. ps thx for edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give @KevinWhite a biscuit / cookie for being first to point out that 'Traditional analogue meters were reversed'.

Your meter manual hasn't got a schematic but if you do an image search for 'analog multimeter schematic' you should be able to trace out the battery positive going to the - socket in most of them.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 'simple' analog multimeter with the typical devious circuitry. Note that there are two batteries for the resistance ranges and both head towards the '-' (black) socket. [Click for full resolution.] Source: [Vesselyn.com](http://vesselyn.com/YW5hbG9nLW11bHRpbWV0ZXItc2NoZW1hdGljLWRpYWdyYW0/).*

It's weird, but when you think of it the meter deflects towards full-scale when current comes *in* on the red lead. Therefore the current must come *from* the black lead.

> I tested a simple rectifier diode with the same ohmmeter. I got meter deflection with positive probe on cathode, but no deflection with positive probe on anode. Does that help?

Your results from your diode test confirm that the black lead is more positive than the red on resistance measurement ranges.

Comment: Thx for great answers!

Answer (score 1):

You likely are actually checking the base collector junction.

BC parts have a different (backwards) pin-out from 2N parts.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thx for answer. In both types, pin 2 is the base. So,with either type, if i put the pos probe on pin 2, then i should get meter deflection with neg probe on either of the other 2 pins. Correct?

Comment: @johnywhy depending on the meter...